# check if rope is wrapping the tree

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Suppose I have a rope, described by a list of $2D$ points $r_1, r_2, \;\dots, r_n$, where $r_i$ is connected to $r_{i+1}$ and I have a tree described by a $2D$ point $t$.

How can I check if the rope is tangled in the tree?

[image]

Comment: In the false example, if the tree $t$ is inside the triangle next to $r_9$ and $r_{10}$, is the tree considered wrapped?

Comment: Yes (unless you think it's simpler to consider otherwise). I think it's simpler to imagine that the tree is wrapped if $t$ is inside any polygon formed by the rope.

Comment: Calculate the [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) of the consecutive points along the rope, with respect to the (center of the) tree.

Comment: What if the rope spirals around the tree many times but never self-intersects?

Comment: The winding number interpretation makes the most sense if your rope starts and ends at the same point, making it a loop and ensuring the winding number is an integer. Otherwise the choice of winding number values that are considered "tangled" feels somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: The rope will never start and end in the same position.

Comment: @Daniel How fast of an algorithm are you looking for?

Comment: Im not looking for something super fast, the rope should have at most 50 points, so I can afford something up to O(n³).